# Lisp: Why is it saying that I'm only giving my function one argument?

Tags: parameters, lisp

The code:

```
(defun len (x count)
  (cond ((null x) ())
        (t (+ count 1)
           (len (cdr x)))))
```

I try to call this function with (len '(a b c) 0) and I get an error saying that I'm only sending the function one argument and it requires two.

What am I doing wrong? I'm especially confused because I ran the function once with no errors using this exact same code, but then it decided that it didn't want to work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The `(len '(a b c) 0)` has the right number of arguments, however your recursive call inside the function, `(len (cdr x))`, does not. It's missing a second argument for the count.

On a related note, you're calculating `(+ count 1)`, but then not doing anything with the result of the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Augmenting @sepp2k's answer, what you want to do is to pass the incremented `count` as the second argument to `len`, and, also, return `count` instead of `NIL` for empty arguments:

```
(defun len (x &optional (count 0))
  (if x 
      (len (cdr x) (1+ count))
      count))
```

Comment: No, if the return value were `0`, the return value would always be zero for all lists. Therefore, the return value needs to be `count`.